# What does Hempel mean by "homotopy 3-cell"?

Tags: definition, geometric-topology, low-dimensional-topology

I am reading *John Hempel: 3-Manifolds* (specifically Lemma 6.5 on incompressible surfaces) and struggle to find a definition of what a *homotopy 3-cell* is.

Does it mean "an open 3-manifold that is homotopy-equivalent to the interior of a 3-ball"? Does it include simple connectedness at infinity? Is there today an easier definition / characterization (e. g. in the presence of the Poincaré conjecture)?

(For instance, Hempel also uses the term homotopy 3-sphere for what we can now simply call a 3-sphere.)

Comment: This means a compact contractible 3-manifold with boundary. We now know that it is homeomorphic to the 3-ball but in 1976 this was unknown (equivalent to  the Poincare Conjecture in 3d).

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Moishe Kohan stated in his comment it means a contractible compact 3-manifold with $S^2$-boundary, a reference being

> C. H. Edwards Jr.: Products of pseudo cells. Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. 68(6): 583-584 (November 1962).